# Why doesn’t my website update even though the file has been uploaded successfully? (FTP)

Tags: html, sftp, ftp-client, filezilla, cyberduck

I have been trying in vain to update my website. I use the following information for a connection:

- server
- name + password
- port
- SFTP

When I save the file, I get a message that the file was uploaded successfully.
However, the website does not update.

In addition, the file on the server does not seem to correspond to the file displayed on the e.g. homepage.

I am happy about every answer.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: If your server uses a cache such as Varnish Cache, then resources will be cached. You can turn the server cache off by adding rules to `.htaccess`. Check with your web host. If you use a reverse proxy like Cloudflare, then resources are cached (for 24 hours by default).

Comment: mybe you are updating  the wrong folder (ex: main is www, and updates should be in www/html)

Comment: try adding a "cachebuster" to the URI of the ressource eg add `?foo=bar` to the end to see if its a caching issue

Comment: No "cached" appears

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the files are cached so even though you change the files, server might be responding you with cached results. To check if that's the case, open your developer console, then go to Network tab and then refresh your page. When the data is loaded, check if it says "cached" on "Status" column. If so, try force refreshing your page by pressing CTRL+F5.

Comment: There's a few different caches at play. 1. `Chrome's browser cache.` 2. `If you're using a cache plugin on Wordpress, or Drupal, then you have another cache there that you need to clear.` 3. `If you're hosted on a CDN like Cloudflare, then you might have to clear that cache, too`........... Or you can just wait ~24 hours or so, and then check again.

Comment: No actually there are 4 caches, as there is also a DNS cache, but that's probably not the cause if the domain name works. Windows has a DNS cache and the web browser also has a DNS cache. On Chrome deleting cookies and local storage doesn't clear the DNS cache, you have to open `chrome://flags` or `chrome:flags`. Opening an igcognito window disables the DNS cache for the web browser, but not for Windows.

Comment: @msteknoadam Unfortunately, that didn't work. No "cached" appears.

Comment: @Tim-Krs sorry I mentioned wrong.It might say "(memory/disk cache)" on "Size" column. Also, if that isn't the case,it might be Cloudflare cache too if you are using CF. Check for "cf-cache-status" on one of your requests that you think isn't updated "cf-cache-status" in Headers. If it says "HIT",then it's served from CF cache which might be outdated. Check [this](https://getfishtank.ca/blog/cloudflare-cdn-cf-cache-status-headers-explained) page for more info about CF cache statuses. Also check [this](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169246) link for how to reset cache on CF.